# Having issues with the output

Tags: java

This is what I have to do "Write a java application that prompts for the person ’ s information , instantiates an object of class Health Profile for that person and prints the information from that object — including the person ’ s First name , last name , gender , date of birth , height and weight — then calculates and prints the person ’ s age in years , BMI , maximum heart rate and target - heart - rate range . It should also
display the “ BMI values ” chart from Exercise 2 . 33 ." But I am getting errors whenever I run it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HealthProfile {

String firstName;
String lastName;
char gender;
int BirthMonth;
int BirthDay;
int BirthYear;
int height;
int weight;

public HealthProfile(String fName, String lName, char Genderr, int birthMonth, int birthDay, int birthYear, int heightt, int weightt){
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    gender = Genderr;
    BirthMonth = birthMonth;
    BirthDay = birthDay;
    BirthYear = birthYear;
    height = heightt;
    weight = weightt;



}

    HealthProfile() {

    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setBirthMonth(int BirthMonth) {
        this.BirthMonth = BirthMonth;
    }

    public int getBirthMonth() {
        return BirthMonth;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(int BirthDay) {
        this.BirthDay = BirthDay;
    }

    public int getBirthDay() {
        return BirthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int BirthYear) {
        this.BirthYear = BirthYear;
    }

    public int getBirthYear() {
        return BirthYear;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

public int Age(){
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int nowYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int nowMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int nowDay = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
int day = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if (nowMonth > BirthMonth);
return (nowYear - BirthYear);
    }

public double getBMI(){
    return (weight * 703)/(height * height);
}

public int MaxHeartRate(){
 return 220-Age();
}

public double TargetHeartRate(){
return MaxHeartRate() * 0.85 + MaxHeartRate() * 0.5;
 }
}
```

Here is the test part:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HealthProfileTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String DoB;
        String theMonth;
        String theDay;
        String theYear;
        char gender;
        int Month;
        int Day;
        int Year;
        double height = 0.0;
        double weight;
       HealthProfile personalInfo = new HealthProfile();
       System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
       firstName = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
       lastName = input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Male or female: ");
       gender = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
       System.out.println("Enter your date of birth in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
       DoB = input.nextLine();
       theMonth = DoB.substring(0,2);
       theDay = DoB.substring(3,5);
       theYear = DoB.substring(6,10);
       Month = Integer.parseInt(theMonth);
       Day = Integer.parseInt(theDay);
       Year = Integer.parseInt(theYear);
       System.out.println("Enter your height in inches: ");
       height = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
       weight = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Name: " + personalInfo.getFirstName() + personalInfo.getLastName());
       System.out.println("Gender: " + personalInfo.getGender());
       System.out.println("DoB: " + personalInfo.getBirthMonth() + "/" + personalInfo.getBirthDay() + "/" + personalInfo.getBirthYear());
       System.out.println("Height: " + personalInfo.getHeight());
       System.out.println("Weight: " + personalInfo.getWeight());
       System.out.println("Age: " + personalInfo.Age());
       System.out.println("BMI: " + personalInfo.getBMI());
       System.out.printf("Max heart rate: ", personalInfo.MaxHeartRate());
       System.out.printf("Target heart rate: ", personalInfo.TargetHeartRate());
       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println( "BMI VALUES" );
        System.out.println("Underweight: Under 18.5");
        System.out.println("Normal: 18.5-24.9 ");
        System.out.println("Overweight: 25-29.9");
        System.out.println("Obese: 30 or over");
    }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Name: nullnull
Gender: 
DoB: 0/0/0
Height: 0.0
Weight: 0.0
Age: 2013
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at HealthProfile.getBMI(HealthProfile.java:108)
        at HealthProfileTest.main(HealthProfileTest.java:43)
Java Result: 1
```

I know I did everything right but just don't get why it's acting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call methods `setHeight` and `setWeight`. Therefore  those values are still `0` by default given that they are numeric primitive types. Obviously the product of 2 zero values equals `0` and dividing then by `0` produces an `ArithmeticException`

Try calling the methods after accepting the inputs.

```
System.out.println("Enter your height in inches: ");
height = input.nextInt();
personalInfo.setHeight((int) height);
System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
weight = input.nextInt();
personalInfo.setWeight((int) weight);
```

Similarly set the "Birth" fields

```
personalInfo.setBirthMonth(Month);
personalInfo.setBirthDay(Day);
personalInfo.setBirthYear(Year);
```

Aside: Java naming conventions show that variables start with a *lowercase* letter such as `day`, `month` and `year`. Read about them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also, you know anything about the DoB part? I tried doing Month = input.nextInt(); personalInfo.setBirthMonth((int)Month); but no luck :/

Comment: It's still doing the same thing DoB :  0 / 0 / 0 
 Age :  2013

Comment: Nope ,  still   says   0 / 0 / 0   for   the   DoB   and   2013   for   the   age. I've been working on it for the past hour still nothing.

Comment: Cant replicate that. If you call the methods as show in the update it should work. Failing that it might be best to post another question

Answer (score 1):

Your exception clearly says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

As you can see in your own output, `height` is 0, so when you get the BMI you divide by 0, which is not a legal operation at:

```
public double getBMI(){
    return (weight * 703)/(height * height);
}
```

Make sure you run your program fully and input a valid height.

Also, as @jlordo pointed out, your code is doing integer division (since all the values involved are integers. This will make you lose anything after the decimal point. Try using:

```
public double getBMI(){
    return ((double)weight * 703)/(height * height);
}
```

Instead. Casting one of the involved values to a `double` makes Java keep the decimal values around.

Comment: You should also note that this code performs integer division, so it will always cut off everything after the decimal point.

Comment: @jlordo Ah yes. Didn't catch that. I'll edit that into the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your following method, change it to something like this:

```
public double getBMI(){
   if(height == 0)
       return (weight * 703)/(height * height);
   else
       return x;   // x is whatever the value you want
}
```

Comment: Look. If and `height` is zero, it will throw an exception again. It should be like: `if(height != 0) { return (weight * 703)/(height * height);} else {return x;}`

Comment: @brano88 I am using the `OR` operator, so it will not cause the exception again

Comment: Why would you use it at all? Only check if `height` is zero.